# How can I configure mod_proxy not specifically not cache 503 errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

This is my mod_proxy config:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /manage/ http://localhost:9000/manage/
ProxyPassReverse /manage/ http://localhost:9000/manage/
</IfModule>
```

I find that whenever the other website I have on port 9000 doesn't respond correctly, I get sustained 503 errors - that persist even after the website is fixed. In other words, the 503 response seems to be cached.

How can I disable it? I don't think I have enabled caching myself, perhaps this is the default.

Comment: It seems that mod-proxy itself does not do any caching. Did you check your browser cache?

Comment: @Khaled - check out the answer by Shane.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod_proxy returns 503 errors even after proxied service is back up](http://serverfault.com/questions/265199/mod-proxy-returns-503-errors-even-after-proxied-service-is-back-up)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

mod_proxy marks an unresponsive backend as down when it seems to be down; if no backends are available then it responds with a 503.

By default, a down backend will be marked as such for 60 seconds; until that time passes, it won't retry the connection (and replies with an error message to any connecting clients).

To have it retry immediately, add `retry=0` to your `ProxyPass` directive:

```
ProxyPass /manage/ http://localhost:9000/manage/ retry=0
```